# Getting the sum of similar values in a Python dictionary

Tags: python, collections, dictionary

Sorry I am back again. This time I am trying to get number of registration per carpark and have added the following code:

```
data_dict = {}
dict_list = []
def createNameDict(filename):
  path = "C:\Users\user\Desktop"
  basename = "ParkingData_Part2.txt"
  filename = path + "//" + basename
  file = open(filename)
  contents = file.read()
  print contents,"\n"


  data_list = [lines.split(",") for lines in contents.split("\n")]



  for line in data_list:
    regNumber = line[0]
    name = line[1]
    phoneExtn = line[2]
    carpark = line[3]
    details = (name,phoneExtn,carpark)

    data_dict[regNumber] = details
  print data_dict,"\n"
  print data_dict.items(),"\n"

def getDetails(regNumber):
  try:
    print data_dict[regNumber]
  except:
    print regNumber, " not in dictionary"
    return
def addRegistration(regNumber, details):
  if regNumber not in data_dict:
    data_dict[regNumber] = details

    print regNumber, ":", details, "Registration details added"
  else:
    print regNumber, "Key Already exist, \n"


  return data_dict
def registrationsPerCarpark(carpark):

  for regNumber, details in data_dict:        
    return [key for key, value in data_dict.iteritems() if value == details][0]
  #for carpark in data_dict.values():
   # print sum(int(carpark))
    #return
```

but the values are not adding up because they are not numerical. I have searched a lot in Google but couldn't get any information regarding this. The output of my code is this way:

```
====== Loading Progam =======
>>> createNameDict("C:\Users\user\Desktop//ParkingData_Part2.txt")
EDF768, Bill Meyer, 2456, Vet_Parking
TY5678, Jane Miller, 8987, AgHort_Parking
GEF123, Jill Black, 3456, Creche_Parking
ABC234, Fred Greenside, 2345, AgHort_Parking
GH7682, Clara Hill, 7689, AgHort_Parking
JU9807, Jacky Blair, 7867, Vet_Parking
KLOI98, Martha Miller, 4563, Vet_Parking
ADF645, Cloe Freckle, 6789, Vet_Parking
DF7800, Jacko Frizzle, 4532, Creche_Parking
WER546, Olga Grey, 9898, Creche_Parking
HUY768, Wilbur Matty, 8912, Creche_Parking 

{'HUY768': (' Wilbur Matty', ' 8912', ' Creche_Parking'), 'GH7682': (' Clara Hill', ' 7689', ' AgHort_Parking'), 'GEF123': (' Jill Black', ' 3456', ' Creche_Parking'), 'WER546': (' Olga Grey', ' 9898', ' Creche_Parking'), 'TY5678': (' Jane Miller', ' 8987', ' AgHort_Parking'), 'ABC234': (' Fred Greenside', ' 2345', ' AgHort_Parking'), 'KLOI98': (' Martha Miller', ' 4563', ' Vet_Parking'), 'EDF768': (' Bill Meyer', ' 2456', ' Vet_Parking'), 'JU9807': (' Jacky Blair', ' 7867', ' Vet_Parking'), 'DF7800': (' Jacko Frizzle', ' 4532', ' Creche_Parking'), 'ADF645': (' Cloe Freckle', ' 6789', ' Vet_Parking')} 

[('HUY768', (' Wilbur Matty', ' 8912', ' Creche_Parking')), ('GH7682', (' Clara Hill', ' 7689', ' AgHort_Parking')), ('GEF123', (' Jill Black', ' 3456', ' Creche_Parking')), ('WER546', (' Olga Grey', ' 9898', ' Creche_Parking')), ('TY5678', (' Jane Miller', ' 8987', ' AgHort_Parking')), ('ABC234', (' Fred Greenside', ' 2345', ' AgHort_Parking')), ('KLOI98', (' Martha Miller', ' 4563', ' Vet_Parking')), ('EDF768', (' Bill Meyer', ' 2456', ' Vet_Parking')), ('JU9807', (' Jacky Blair', ' 7867', ' Vet_Parking')), ('DF7800', (' Jacko Frizzle', ' 4532', ' Creche_Parking')), ('ADF645', (' Cloe Freckle', ' 6789', ' Vet_Parking'))] 

>>> registrationsPerCarpark("AgHort_Parking")
The error was:__getitem__
Attribute not found.
You are trying to access a part of the object that doesn't exist.
Please check line 48 of C:\Users\user\Desktop\159171\assignment2_part2
```

Answer (score 0):

The line `for regNumber, details in data_dict` is wrong, you can't iterate over a dict that way. You probably meant `for regNumber, details in data_dict.items()` (or `iteritems()`, but that will be Python 2 specific).

If I understand the task right, the function body should look somewhat like the following:

```
def registrationsPerCarpark(carpark):

    return sum(value[2]=carpark for value in data_dict.values())
```

And mind the spaces in your values: for instance, you should be looking for `' AgHort_Parking'`, not `'AgHort_Parking'`. To solve that, change `createNameDict` to do

```
carpark = line[3].strip()
```

and so on.
Also, `createNameDict` is memory-inefficient, because it loads file contents into the memory at once. To decrease memory usage, do:

```
data_list = []
with open(filename) as infile:
  data_list = [lines.split(",") for lines in contents.split("\n")]
  for line in infile:
        data_list.append(line.split(','))
        print line
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def registrationsPerCarpark(carpark):
    for regNumber, details in data_dict:        
        return [key for key, value in data_dict.iteritems() if value == details][0]
```

Your `for` loop will not work because the `in dictionary` construct for iteration only returns the `key`, and not the `(key, value)` pair.  Secondly you never use the `carpark` variable. Thirdly it is extraneous as you're are looping through it afterwards in your return statement, although your usage of it makes no sense.  One could assume you just needed to count how many cars were at a specific car park ?

Comment: yes I want count number of cars at a given carpark, but i dont know what method to use. I searched a lot but couldnt find anything.

Comment: A fairly wordy example would be to use `for _, _, parking_lot in data_dict.iteritems():` which will automagically unpack the value tuple, and then compare the `parking_lot` var with what the user is looking for, and adding it up whichever way you prefer.  There are more concise ways to lay it out, but I will leave that as an exercise for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another, more compact approach.

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

rows = defaultdict(set)

with open('in.csv') as f:
  lines = csv.reader(f)
  for line in lines:
      rows[line[3].strip()].add((line[0],line[1],line[2]))

for key in rows:
   print 'Total number of cars for %s is %s' % (key,len(rows[key]))
```

The result of this is:

```
The total number of cars for Creche_Parking is 4
The total number of cars for AgHort_Parking is 3
The total number of cars for Vet_Parking is 4
```